# Can someone show me how to modify a txt file in c++ ? ( i`m working in codeblocks)

Tags: c++, arrays, text, vector

So i have a txt file like this:

3/1995       13,25,16,14

4/1995       36,1,24,48

5/1996       39,46,35,2

233/1996     14,16,25,12

And i want to modify it to look like this, in another txt file:

13,25,16,14

36,1,24,48

39,46,35,2

14,16,25,12

I also want to transform them from char to int and put them in a 2d vector.
This is what i tried so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

static const int WIDTH = 10;
static const int HEIGHT = 50;

       int main()
{
    char level[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

    ifstream file;
    file.open("new.txt");

     for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
        {

         file>>level[i][j];
         cout<<level[i][j];
        }cout<<endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

And it doesn`t read the blank space so it just messes up everything.

Comment: So you want to delete the numbers in the front, wich is quite easy:
Get the line as a whole with `getline()` (reference: [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/) ). Then you have to simply erase the string you got from the beginning to the first blank.

Is see you have always 4 numbers in your line left then, therefore you could also erase from the string that is left all the "," symbols and create a stringstream object.

Answer (score 1):

In order to gather all characters including white spaces, I advise you to use "get" instead of the << operator.

EDIT : or getline as suggested

In order to apply to change you describe, it's quite easy as basically each line is made out of two string and you always want to keep the second one only.

So you'd just have to do, for every line, file >> "a string" >> "a string"; (you could actually use the same), and for the file you want the write the result : file2 << "a string"; (the second one you use if not always the same)

NOTE : there are probably better ways to do it, just the easier that came to my mind